# Managing JDialog close behaviour

Tags: java, forms, swing, jdialog

I'm using a JDialog window to display a form of "pin entry" window before my actual application is shown. Since I seem to be unable to hide the close button, I'm trying to control what happens when this button is clicked. The objective is to make the dialog open itself again (thus preventing access to the form behind it unless the correct PIN is entered), but WindowListener does not seem to be the correct approach.

```
pinDialog = new JDialog();
pinDialog.setSize(300, 208);
pinDialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
pinDialog.setVisible(true);
pinDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdaptor(){
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
        {
            //things to open the dialog again here
        }
    });
```

The final statement here (addWindowListener) appears not to be the correct type for the WindowAdaptor argument, however I have seen many examples using this exact approach. Is the problem because I am using a JDialog rather than a new frame altogether?

Comment: you might need to override the method in the `WindowAdaptor`constructor

Comment: set the close operation ?? setDefaultCloseOperation() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but WindowListener does not seem to be the correct approach.

You also need to use:

```
 dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

when you create the dialog. Then you can control the behaviour in your WindowListener.

Check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for more information. The article is for a frame but the basics are valid for a dialog as well.

Comment: So DefaultCloseOperation and the WindowListener work in tandem? Because I have tried using the former alone with no effect.

Comment: The IDE, however, is still complaining that "addWindowListener in the type Window is not applicable for the argument new WindowAdaptor"...

Comment: @Wolfish -  Read the JDialog API and you will see that you can add a WindowListener to the dialog. I never use an IDE to generate my code. I don't know what the problem is. Maybe the problem is that you try to add the listener to the dialog after the dialog is visible. That won't work because that statement is only executed after the dialog has been closed which defeats the purpose of using the WindowListener.

Comment: I'm not sure how, the WindowListener has to be available when the dialog is visible because I'm listening for the dialog *to* be closed...

Comment: But I can see that it should definitely work. I'm also, however, seeing a compiler error so I'll try move it around as you suggest

Comment: @Wolfish, Did you import the package for the WindowAdapter? If you can't solve your problem then poste a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). That is you create a simple class with a main() method. Then you have 1 statement to create the dialog, another to set the close operation, another to add the WindowListener and another to make the dialog visible. So the whole class is about 10 lines of code. Get that working first so you understand the concept before you add it to your real application. This is basic debugging, learninig how to simplify the problem.

Comment: I think I've largely solved the problem by using "implements WindowAdapter", at the very least it has compiled without complaint

Comment: As for *why* this  occurred... I couldn't say. I've been working in Eclipse for all of two days.